# How to change json url name on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json

I have a section which contains a 'Preview' button. This section has a URL like this:

```
https://www.interactive-video.videomill.pl/editorv1/?schemat=Sandra
```

On clicking the preview button, it opens another page:

```
$("#main-btn-preview").on('click', function() {                    
  var url = "/editorv1/preview.html"         
})
```

The preview.html page has a JS file named main.js which looks like this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('moviedata/data.json', function(data) {
    var movies = data.movies;
    $.getJSON('datasaved/settings2.json', function(data) {
      var flowchart = data.movies;
    })
  })
})
```

On clicking the preview button I want to change the URL in `getJSON`. If the URL is `https://www.interactive-video.videomill.pl/editorv1/?schemat=Sandra` it should change the getJSON URL like this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.getJSON('moviedata/sandra.json', function(data) {
    var movies = data.movies;
    $.getJSON('datasaved/sandra.json', function(data) {
      var flowchart = data.movies;
    })
  })
})
```

The JSON filename comes from the URL parameter `schemat=Sandra`. What do I need to change to get what I want?

Comment: If you have control over the contents of `editorv1` you can pick up the value from the  `schemat` get param, if it just rewrite to .html file you could just place that value in localstorage and on load of that second page just grab it or even parse out window.location.search if your feeling adventurous

Comment: also there is [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: Thanks lawrance , I did exactly as you expalin and everything works perfectly